# integrating webpack-dev-server with node\express\socket.io

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

In order to start using react on my app, i installed webpack and Webpack-dev-server on my node server. when launching the webpack dev server from the terminal, it translates my React\es6 code to JavaScript and sends it to the client as expected, but it does not launch any of my server code. I tried to instead require Webpack in my node code like this:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
webpack({
    entry: './src/App.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
...
...
```

and launch my regular node server but then the Webpack actually created the compiled files instead of just sending them to the client (I assume this behavior is something i will only need on production).
How can I tell webppack-dev-server to launch my server code (the index.js file with all the node/express/socket.io) or alternativly how can i use webpack from my node code and make it behave like webpack-dev-server?